# Cache with Spring Data Rest

Tags: caching, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

i'm looking to make cache on severale Spring Data Rest repositories, is there any way to activate cache by repository, not just by controller endpoint ?

Comment: Can you add code for one or more of your repositories and point out which methods you would like to enable caching for? Difficult to help out without any code.

Comment: i don't want to target an exact methode but i wanna make a cache for REST repository , so if table (repository) if updated it gonna read from data base, unless it is gonna read frm cache.

Comment: Again, add your code, otherwise your question is not a good fit for this site and risks being closed.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362173/spring-data-rest-caching

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring's `@Cacheable` annotation.
i.e.

```
@Cacheable({"books", "isbns"})
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn) {...}
```

See Spring documentation for more information on all use cases:[Spring Cache Abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable)